# PHP How to process parallel arrays, convert and return concatenated values

Tags: php, arrays, string, concatenation

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to make my function return a concatenated list of converted strings. The goal is to process 2 parallel arrays and use the value in one array ('U' or 'L') to cause the value (words) in the parallel array to convert to all upper or lower case, using a loop.

I want to return a concatenated list of the converted results.

I want no parameters to be used.

Right now it's just returning the first word, I'm not sure how to make it return the whole array of words. Any help is appreciated!

```
<?php

$case[0]='U';    // I just made these arrays up for the purpose of testing
$case[1]='L';    // the $case array values will be either U or L
$case[2]='U';
$case[3]='L';

$strings[0]='tHese';    // the $strings array values are words of varying case
$strings[1]='aRe';
$strings[2]='rAndoM';
$strings[3]='wOrDs';



function changeCase () {
    global $case;      
    global $strings;

    $total = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($case); $i++) {
        if ($case[$i] == "U") return strtoupper($strings[$i]);
        elseif ($case[$i] == "L") return strtolower($strings[$i]);
        $total = $total + $strings[$i]; //the returned value should look like THESEareRANDOMwords
    }
    return $total;
};

echo changeCase ();
```

?>

Comment: Since you're using a function you're much better off passing the arrays as parameters instead of accessing them as globals.

Comment: the use of the return keyword exits the function.  Rewrite without using return in your for loop

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

function changeCase ($case, $strings) {
    $total = '';
    foreach($case as $i=>$type)
        $total .= ($type=='U') ? strtoupper($strings[$i]) : strtolower($strings[$i]);
    return $total;
}

$case[0]='U';    // I just made these arrays up for the purpose of testing
$case[1]='L';    // the $case array values will be either U or L
$case[2]='U';
$case[3]='L';

$strings[0]='tHese';    // the $strings array values are words of varying case
$strings[1]='aRe';
$strings[2]='rAndoM';
$strings[3]='wOrDs';

echo changeCase($case, $strings);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `return` in the loop, which will get you out of the function. You never reach the `$total=...` part.

Comment: Oh okay, I thought since the return is after the curly bracket that closes the for loop it was alright.

Answer (score 0):

`array_map()` is perfect for this.

```
$case[0]='U';    
$case[1]='L';    
$case[2]='U';
$case[3]='L';

$strings[0]='tHese';    
$strings[1]='aRe';
$strings[2]='rAndoM';
$strings[3]='wOrDs';

// Set up an anonymous function to run on $case, and pass in $strings
$funct = function($value, $key) use ($strings) {            
    if($value == "U")
        return strtoupper($strings[$key]);
    else
        return strtolower($strings[$key]);  
};

// Pass in our keys as an additional parameter, this is not usual 
// but in this case we need the keys to access the $strings array
$results = array_map($funct, $case, array_keys($case));

var_dump(implode("", $results));
```